# angular $controller locals substitue

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I am using `$controller` service to inherit controller.

I have something like this

```
angular.module('myModule', ['someModule'])
   .controller('parentController', parentController)
   .controller('childController', childController);

parentController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'someModule.defaultService'];
childController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'someModule.myService'];

function parentController($scope, defaultService) {
        $scope.value = defaultService.someMethod();
}

function childController($scope, myService) {
        var viewModel = this;
        var ctrl = $controller('parentController', {
            $scope: $scope, defaultService:myService
        });
        angular.extend(viewModel, ctrl);
}
```

I want to `parentController` using `myService` insted of it's `defaultService`. But it doesn't work. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

uses the correct injection name :

```
var ctrl = $controller('parentController', {
        $scope: $scope, **defaultService**:myService
});
```

But what you're doing seems more of an hack than anything else imho.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made a mistake in example here. I am using correct name, but it doesn't work:(